# Objective C: UILabel not displaying the value that came from another class on runtime

Tags: uilabel, ios5

I have a class here that passes a String value to another class which has a UILabel and display it to that. However i can't display it to the label of another class. I did this in 2 ways..

1)My First Way, directly calling the label from another class
.On my first class, on the method

```
static void on_status_state(NSString *) stats
{
     DisplayViewController* display = [[DisplayViewController alloc] init];
        display.statusLabel.text = @"Sample Display";
}
```

On the class which contains the UILabel.
On DisplayConn.h

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *statusLabel;
```

2) My Second way, Calling a method and pass the value to a parameter
on my first class, on the method

```
static void on_status_state(NSString *) stats
{
  DisplayViewController* display = [[DisplayViewController alloc] autorelease];
        [display toReceiveStatus:@"Sample Label"];
}
```

On the class which contains the UILabel.
On DisplayConn.h

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *statusLabel;
```

then on the DisplayConn.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)toReceiveStatus:(NSString *) stats
{
    self.statusLabel.text = stats;
    NSLog(@"DISPLAY %@",stats); 
}
```

The second way seems to be working because the log which contains the value is displayed, however the value is still not displayed to the label('statusLabel'). The display to label changes on runtime from time to time.
What should be the cause?

Comment: i think i forgot to mention I'm using Xcode4.3, storyboard in my development

Answer (score 1):

Consider this,

Class A and B

UILabel is in class B

in Class A,

```
B *newObject = [B alloc]init];
newObject.statusLabelValue = @"Simple Display";
```

and in your B.h

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *statusLabelValue;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *statusLabel;
```

and

in B.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
statusLabel.text = statusLabelValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I think this would only work the first time or every time the screen loads. The UILabel of my application should be updating from time to time even without leaving the screen. Updates are runtime.

Comment: That is because of I just placed the code inside the viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the object of  `DisplayViewController` class,

```
 static void on_status_state(NSString *) stats
{
        DisplayViewController* display = [[[DisplayViewController alloc]  init] autorelease];
        [display toReceiveStatus:@"Sample Label"];
}
```

You should check `- (void)toReceiveStatus:` is called or not. Declare statusLabel in DisplayConn.h as `UILabel *statusLabel;`

Try like this i think it will be helpful to you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    statusLabel  = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 20)];
    statusLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14];
    statusLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
    [self.view addSubview:statusLabel];

}
```

Comment: Yes. the method from the second class is certainly called. Actually i could display the passed value on logs, its only the UILabel that is not updating the value.

Comment: Yes the log is displaying the value passed

Comment: You should debug, it will work. Write NSLog(@"DISPLAY Str %@", statusLabel.text); in - (void)toReceiveStatus: method and check it.

Comment: Sorry its the parameter that is displaying. But when i log the UILabel statusLabel.text = stats;
 NSLog(@"DISPLAY Str %@", statusLabel.text);, it shows (null)... Why the value was not set to UILabel? hmm...

Comment: How did you declare statusLabel?

Comment: on my header file, it is declared as '@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *statusLabel;'

Comment: Don't do like that. Declare statusLabel in DisplayConn.h as UILabel *statusLabel; and you write to create dynamically UILabel as i wrote code in viewDidLoad.

Comment: ok so i follow what you do. ON my header file, i declare UILabel *statusLabel; then on the implementation - (void)viewDidLoad
{ statusLabel properties...[self.view addSubview:statusLabel]; }, next on my - (void)toReceiveStatus:(NSString *) stats { statusLabel.text = stats;
 NSLog(@"DISPLAY Str %@", statusLabel.text); } ...still when i run the code, it builds the view, OK, then when i receive a value then set it to UILabel, the value of statusLabel is still (null).